# Debugging QT project in Eclipse is very slow (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, qt, gdb

I'm trying to debug a sample QT project in eclipse in Ubuntu. Launching debugger hangs at 93% for several minutes. Then every step of debugging is very slow.

I tried to debug a simple hello-world-program. Debugger flies. So, the problem is with QT.

Looks like gdb traces terminal prints a very very long PATH, can't see the beginning, ends with this:

```
...:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/lzo:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/raid6:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/raid6/test:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/reed_solomon:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/xz:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/zlib_inflate:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic-pae/lib/zlib_deflate:$cdir:$cwd
```

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the debugger is trying to load a lot of symbols for the said program (including Qt) and this may take quite a while (so, it's not Qt-specific.)